# Which Amadeus API will return the flight details with price?

Tags: api, amadeus

I am working on the Amadeus API and using the Air_MultiAvailability. it gives me the flight search results data but not giving me the flight price. SO i need to get the all the flight details with price.

I don't know that i am using the correct API or not but i looking the flight search data with price details.

Kindly help

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get started quickly to test, you may want to consider using the [Amadeus Travel Innovation Sandbox](https://sandbox.amadeus.com/) [Flight Low Fare Search API](https://sandbox.amadeus.com/travel-innovation-sandbox/apis/get/flights/low-fare-search).

If you are using Amadeus Web Services, a good starting point is the **Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch** message. The *Amadeus WBS Implementation Guide - Internet Booking Engine with Master Pricer* document which you can find on the webservices portal may also be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can have both price and availibility with a product like MasterPricer.

Otherwise you should use Fare_PricePNRWithBookingClass

Answer (score 0):

I have just used the Amadeus and find the flight search and flight details and also FlightBooking.

To get the Flight Search use **Fare_MastepricerTravelBoardSearch**
To Get the Flight Details with Price  use Fare_InformativeBestPricingWithoutPNR

if you need more info please ask, i am able to answer related to Amadeus

Comment: What language did you implement the Web Service in?

I have POC access and have the WSDL. Would like to connect to the Web Service using Node is possible

Comment: After fetching Fare_MastepricerTravelBoardSearch function I got few arrays. With price details array I got the flight details and with recommendation array, I got price array. But I cant connect flight details with price. What is the relational parameter between them?